# Search for exact tuple/list/series in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I need to find an exact match of tuple/series in a dataframe with two columns of tuple/series like so:

```
Tuple = (10, 0, 0)

pandas.Dataframe =             From                    To
                    2      (10.0, 0.0, 0.0)      (20.0, 0.0, 0.0)
                    3     (10.0, -0.0, 0.0)    (18.66, -5.0, 0.0)
                    4     (10.0, -0.0, 0.0)    (15.0, -8.66, 0.0)
                    5    (15.0, -8.66, 0.0)   (20.0, -17.32, 0.0)
                    6   (20.0, -17.32, 0.0)  (11.34, -12.32, 0.0)
                    7    (15.0, -8.66, 0.0)    (25.0, -8.66, 0.0)
                    8  (11.34, -12.32, 0.0)   (1.34, -12.32, 0.0)
                    9   (1.34, -12.32, 0.0)   (10.0, -17.32, 0.0)
```

Here it should return indices 2, 3, 4

Thanks

PS. I say tuple/series because I don't know which one would be most efficient. I can use either or

Comment: Is this in pandas?

Comment: Apologies, yes in pandas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
print(DataFrame[(DataFrame['From'] == Tuple) | (DataFrame['To'] == Tuple)].index.values)
```

Comment: And for both columns just print(DataFrame[DataFrame['from', 'to'] == Tuple])?

Comment: @ZackJoubert No that easy: `print(DataFrame[(DataFrame['from'] == Tuple) | (DataFrame['to'] == Tuple)])`

Comment: This works but prints the whole line. How to get the indices only? Also, how do you format code in the comments?